# How to change the color of the title separator line in the title page in beamer?

Tags: beamer

I'd like to change the color of the orange horizontal line in the title page of a beamer presentation based on the `metropolis` theme.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
  
\title{How to change the color of the orange line?}
\date{May, 2022}
\author{Author}
\institute{University}

\begin{document}

\maketitle % Why this warning? Overfull \vbox (15.63992pt too high) detected at line 11

\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{33, 117, 0}
\setbeamertemplate{title separator}{fg=mygreen, bg=mygreen}
```

I tried also the code written in the [official documentation](https://tug.org/docs/latex/beamertheme-metropolis/metropolistheme.pdf), at page 21, but it doesn't work too.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\newlength{\metropolis@titleseparator@linewidth}
\setlength{\metropolis@titleseparator@linewidth}{0.4pt}
\setbeamertemplate{title separator}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[fg] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth, \metropolis@titleseparator@linewidth);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\par%
}
```

Am I missing something or it is a more difficult task than one can think? I thought there was a simple one-line command, but maybe I was too optimistic.

p.s. I noticed that the compiler gives a warning at the line `\maketitle`, is it normal?

```
Overfull \vbox (15.63992pt too high) detected at line 11
```

---

### UPDATE

The second code works with a slight modification (namely I had to add `\makeatletter` and replace `\fill[fg]` with `\fill[mygreen]`)

```
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{33, 117, 0}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\metropolis@titleseparator@linewidth}{1pt}
\setbeamertemplate{title separator}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[mygreen] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth, \metropolis@titleseparator@linewidth);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\par%
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\setbeamercolor` instead of `\setbeamertemplate` works:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
  
\title{How to change the color of the orange line?}
\date{May, 2022}
\author{Author}
\institute{University}

\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{33, 117, 0}
\setbeamercolor{title separator}{fg=mygreen, bg=mygreen}


\begin{document}

\maketitle % Why this warning? Overfull \vbox (15.63992pt too high) detected at line 11

\end{document}
```

The warning must have had something to do with this silent error, too, because it went away after making this change.

Comment: Thanks! I feel a bit stupid now, how did I not try that? :) The warning is still there in my editor (overleaf) but I don't think it's a big problem